# How to update with join for null values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I ma updating the my spatial data using `update from` like folowing.

```
update ways w
    set end_node_id = n.node_id
from nodes n
where st_endpoint(w.shape) = n.shape 
   and w.created_at >= current_date 
   and w.created_at < current_date + interval '1 day';
```

This query updates the `end_node_id` of way with `node_id` of nodes table. But if any node deleted or moded to another location, the `end_node_id` should set as null after the query run again.

How can I change this sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the simplest method is to set everything to `NULL` before doing the update:

```
update ways w
    set end_node_id = NULL;
```

Then your update will change the `NULL` to something else.  This does incur the overhead of updating some (many?) rows twice.  But it is simple.

An alternative method requires a primary key on `ways`; let me call that `way_id`:

```
update ways w
    set end_node_id = n.node_id
from ways w2 left join
     nodes n
     on st_endpoint(w2.shape) = n.shape
where w2.way_id = w.way_id;
```

Comment: @barteloma restrict the NULL-update , using NOT EXISTS()

Comment: I do not need first query end_node_id = NULL, the second is working.

Comment: You would still touch all the rows. (and that was the essense of your deleted comment)